# How do I set value in an independent child component in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have an inline edit component that works without any dependencies with other components, In one situation, I wish to trigger the edit view of the component from a parent component.

The component uses one variable called `editing` that toggles the edit view

```
// my-parent-component template
<div>
    <editable v-for="item in items" v-model="item" type="text">
    </editable>
</div>

// my-editing-component template
<div>
    <div v-if="!editing" v-text="value" @click="edit"></div>
    <div v-if="editing"><input v-model="value" @keydown.enter="done"/></div>
</div>
```

The editable component is

```
export default {
    name : 'editable',
    props: ['value','type']
    data : function(){
        return {
            editing: false;
        }
    }
    methods : {
        edit(){
            this.editing = true;
        },
        done(){
            this.editing = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Now the challenge is I have a global listener for `enter` key and I maintain index of "active" item in the parent component.

When the user hits enter, I want to trigger edit of the active "item".

I can pass it as

```
<editable v-for="(item,index) in items" v-model="item" :editing="index == active" ></editable>
```

But that prop "editing" will not be in other places where I use the editable component

Is it ok to set property from the parent like this: `this.$refs.editable.editing = true`

From the documentation I understand that Its not possible to send a event to the child component.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi Masade, you have considered using central state management with Vuex for example?

Comment: Yeah, I am already using vuex to manage state for rest of application, however i wish this component "editable" is to be used in other applications. So using store may not be right.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you should pass props to child components in order to control their states. But if you want a hacky access to children state, there are several workarounds:

1. use `ref` pointers on children (though it requires actual `ref` placed),
2. access component's children with `this.$children`.

`this.$children` requires some additional logic probably, where you decide which index of the array you need to access. It depends on your application.

Usage example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    toggleChild: function() {
      this.$refs['editMe'].editable = !this.$refs['editMe'].editable;
      // different approach without 'ref':
      // this.$children[0].editable = !this.$children[0].editable;
    }
  },
  components: {
    'child' : {
      template: `<p>{{ editable }}</p>`,
      data: function() {
       return {
          editable: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child ref="editMe"></child>
  <button @click="toggleChild">Toggle editable inside child</button>
</div>
```